# Set DNS on VM in Windows Azure

Tags: windows, iis, azure, dns

When create a VM on Windows Azure, and set up an IIS server I can access by dns provided by Azure.
There is a way, for set my domain to an asp.net application?

Like, mysite.com on iis of my VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your own domain/DNS management and setup a CNAME alias for the Azure generated DNS entry.

Comment: You need to check with your name registrar. Do they offer DNS?  You will have to check with who ever you have your DNS with. You could use something like http://www.cloudns.net/ to host your DNS if your registrar does not provide one.